# Add a string to SQL select

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am using SQL reporting service and working on paramters.  One of paramters contains a list of cities.  So, I have a dataset that

```
select city from MyCities
```

What I would like to do is to add a string for selecting all cities. So, I modifed the query to do something like

```
select city from Mycities union select 'ALL'
```

Only problem with this is that I want to show on the top of list so that it will be first itme on the list.

Is there a way I can sort the list so that it shows "All" first and followed by the name of actual cities?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do this a lot and typically just wrap it with special characters, so that it stands out as well:

```
  SELECT City
  FROM (
    SELECT City
    FROM MyCities
    UNION SELECT '<<ALL>>'
  ) X
  ORDER BY City;
```

That will push it to the top of the list

Answer (score 2):

Could you not do `select 'ALL' union select city from Mycities`

Comment: You're taking advantage of the result **usually** being in that order, but it's not guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT City
FROM
(
    SELECT City, 1 AS Sorter FROM MyCities
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'ALL' AS City, 0 AS Sorter
) iq
ORDER BY iq.Sorter ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it would be something like:

```
select 'ALL'
union
select city from Mycities
```

However you may receive a message about the amount of columns, so you may have to add blank '' to make it fit.

Comment: There is only 1 column in both `SELECT`s

Answer (score 0):

This would work to:

```
select 1 as id,'All' as city
union all 
select 2,city from mycities
order by id,name
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `select 'ALL'  union select city from Mycities` actually works, but at any rate it isn't guaranteed, so you can do:

```
Select city
from (Select 'ALL' as city, 1 as myOrder
      union
      select city,2 as myOrder from Mycities)
order by myOrder
```